# the real rate of decline

Tags: financial-literacy

This figure is being reported by the media- U.S. gross domestic product, or GDP, tumbled by an annualized rate of 32.9 percent in the three months through June

since this is a misleading number - what is the best way to reflect the decline m/m or q/q?

Comment: What's misleading about this number?

Answer (score 3):

Using month on month or quarter on quarter doesn't give you a number that is comparable to annual GDP growth as you will see a sharp decline and then a sharp increase later on which will be based on a moving monthly or quarterly bases which doesn't let you get a good reference point. This is also because 50% decline followed by 50% increase is a 25% decline from the first reference point. Additionally, there is seasonality to take care of when using m-o-m or q-o-q so annualizing is the better option.

Comment: +1 better answer than mine. Still unclear what OP feels is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty clear to me what "annualized rate of 32.9 percent" means.

How about the Government just offers the number for each quarter and lets you do the math as you wish?